# Не работают cookie

Tags: php, cookie

В общем код простейший

```
setcookie('test', 'test', time()+86400, '/');
```

В куки ничего не пишется. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: У вас перед вызовом setcookie никакого вывода в броузер нет?

Comment: Добрый день! Скорее всего не пишутся по одной из двух причин: [здесь описано](https://knasys.ru/setcookie-php-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82/).

Answer (score 2):

Возможные проблемы:

1. Прием куки отключен у юзверя
2. У вас перед установкой куки был вывод в броузер (пусть даже пробел или перевод строки)
3. Если вы ищите куки в $_COOKIE в том же скрипте, где и установили его, то не найдете. Только при следующем запуске скрипта

   ```
    if(setcookie('test', 'test', time()+86400, '/')) 
       echo "Кука установлен";
    else
       echo "Кука не установлен";
   ```

Но если setcookie() вернет true - это еще не значит, что он появится у клиента, ведь он мог отключить прием куков. Лучше почитайте про сессии.

Comment: Прием cookie у пользователя включен, но они все равно не принимаются.

Comment: @vitagame, попробуйте посмотреть возвращаемые заголовки (через консоль/расширение хрома или с помощью curl). Там должен быть Set-cookie: траляля.

Comment: Ну а значение, возвращенное setcookie() проверили?

Comment: Проверял. Куки не установлены.

Comment: А можете из другого скрипта вызвать следующий код и показать нам вывод?

<?php
$url = 'Полный УРЛ к странице, которая должна выставить куки';

print_r(get_headers($url));

?>